# "There's no line here to end" error using \item command

Tags: overleaf

Getting the error in the title at this line:

`\item {Hack 24} Worked in a team called Hackbox where I helped to create a version of the game Battleships.`

Here is the code in full. I'm using Overleaf to write a CV

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (8/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Trey Hunner (http://www.treyhunner.com/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the resume.cls file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The resume.cls file provides the resume style used for structuring the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Joshua Diamond} % Your name
\address{13 Langley Crescent Edgware HA8 9SZ} % Your address
%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{Mob: +44 7908899764 \\ joshuadiamond@live.co.uk} % Your phone number and email
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University of Nottingham} \hfill {\em Enrolled since September 2017} 
\\ Foundation Year in Engineering and Physical Science \hfill {Achieved 2:1}
\\ Computer Science with Artificial Intelligence {On course for a 2:1}  
%Minor in Linguistics \smallskip \\
%Member of Eta Kappa Nu \\
%Member of Upsilon Pi Epsilon \\


\end{rSection}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TECHNICAL STRENGTHS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Technical Strengths}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Programming Languages &  Proficient in C, Java, Python. Learning Javascript, SQL, C++ \\
Software \& Tools & HTML, Excel, Matlab \\
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}
\begin{rSubsection} {Hackathons}
\item {Hack 24} Worked in a team called Hackbox where I helped to create a version of the game Battleships.
\item {Hack Sheffield}
\item Taught myself about PyGame.
\end{rSubsection}


%------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSubsection}{Coursework}

\item Linked Lists: Implemented insertion and merge sorts in C using Linked Lists 
\item Encryption: Used watermarking algorithm and created a GUI in MatLab for obfuscating text in PNG files.
\item 6502 CPU: Built a 6502 CPU from NAND Gates in Hardware Description Language (HDL).
\item Server and Client: Built a Server and Client in C to implement the RFC-867 Daytime Protocol.
\item Arm Assembly: Built a matching pairs game in Arm Assembly.
\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please include a link to `resume.cls`.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Which `resume.cls` are you using?  In standard classes `\item`s usually appear inside some list environment such as `enumerate` or `itemize`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You've tagged this question [Overleaf], so I guess you're using a template from Overleaf. Could you please include a link to it if that's the case?

Comment: Maybe you should use brackets in your `\item` (so `\item[Hack 24]` instead of your code), that would be the usual syntax of `\item`.

Answer (score 3):

The example coming with `resume.cls` has

```
\begin{rSubsection}{ACME, Inc}{October 2010 - Present}{Web Developer}{Palo Alto, CA}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
\item Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero Adobe Coldfusion egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
\item Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem Microsoft SQL lacinia consectetur.
\item Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat JavaScript sagittis.
\item Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bash bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies.
\end{rSubsection}
```

Note that the `rSubsection` command has four arguments and you're just supplying one.

If I supply dummy arguments, there is no error.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (8/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Trey Hunner (http://www.treyhunner.com/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the resume.cls file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The resume.cls file provides the resume style used for structuring the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Joshua Diamond} % Your name
\address{13 Langley Crescent Edgware HA8 9SZ} % Your address
%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{Mob: +44 7908899764 \\ joshuadiamond@live.co.uk} % Your phone number and email
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University of Nottingham} \hfill {\em Enrolled since September 2017} 
\\ Foundation Year in Engineering and Physical Science \hfill {Achieved 2:1}
\\ Computer Science with Artificial Intelligence {On course for a 2:1}  
%Minor in Linguistics \smallskip \\
%Member of Eta Kappa Nu \\
%Member of Upsilon Pi Epsilon \\


\end{rSection}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TECHNICAL STRENGTHS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Technical Strengths}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Programming Languages &  Proficient in C, Java, Python. Learning Javascript, SQL, C++ \\
Software \& Tools & HTML, Excel, Matlab \\
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}
\begin{rSubsection}{Hackathons}{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}
\item {Hack 24} Worked in a team called Hackbox where I helped to create a version of the game Battleships.
\item {Hack Sheffield}
\item Taught myself about PyGame.
\end{rSubsection}


%------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSubsection}{Coursework}{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}

\item Linked Lists: Implemented insertion and merge sorts in C using Linked Lists 
\item Encryption: Used watermarking algorithm and created a GUI in MatLab for obfuscating text in PNG files.
\item 6502 CPU: Built a 6502 CPU from NAND Gates in Hardware Description Language (HDL).
\item Server and Client: Built a Server and Client in C to implement the RFC-867 Daytime Protocol.
\item Arm Assembly: Built a matching pairs game in Arm Assembly.
\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

I left `\bf` and `\em`, but note they have been deprecated for more than 20 years.

Supply the required data instead of `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that when you're getting into troubles, make a copy of your file and start tracking down the source of evil in your code. Delete everything which has nothing to do with your problem, these are things completely unrelated with your problem, e.g. if your facing problems with including a picture delete everything except the part and packages you need for the picture. 
Another possibility is to write a new minimum tex file which includes only the picture part. If it's working in there, it should work in your main file. 
In case it does not work in the main file there might be a clash of two packages.

The first problem I faced when copying your code, there was no `resume.sty`.
By switching to the `article` class I wanted to reproduce your error which failed because `rSection` is contained in resume and not in article.

In overleaf I faced the same problem `there is no line to end here` even though we did not call `\\`or `\newline`.

Luckily I used the same template to create my cv. (I used the original version and not the overleaf template)
I had a look into my .tex-file and I was surprised that I did not use any of your items. 
I don't know why you would want to use these items, so just leave them out and go with following:

```
\begin{rSection}{Experience}    

    \textbf{ Latex genius }\hfill\textit{ BigBang - $\infty$ }\\
    {Earth} \textit{Hello}
```

In case you want a dot at the beginning of the line just use $\bullet$.

When you stuck, it is very often a real pain in the ass, until you get down to your problem. Sometimes just use a workaround (write your own code).

btw you used [resume.sty](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv)

In a previous version of my comment I used `\bf` and `\em` which are apparently depreciated since 1994 - oops. Thank you Troy! I never faced problems with them, because I never combined them. You can read more here [Link](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd).

My method might not be the best solution, because I wrote it when I learned LaTeX, but I have a beautiful pdf document. You should go with egreg's answer.

Comment: `\bf` and `\em` are both wrong/deprecated for more than 20 years; and should not be used.